# jest test - TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm quite new with jest testing and I'm having trouble to understand how Jest deals with the functions I'm trying to test. Here's my problem:

I'm trying to test the following, quite simple function, which will receive a bookId and will find the object within an array that containa such id. All is vanilla js, no react.

```
function catchSelectedBook(bookId) {
  const objectSearchAsString = localStorage.getItem('objecttransfer');
  const booksObject = JSON.parse(objectSearchAsString);
  const currentBook = booksObject.filter((book) => book.id === bookId);

  return currentBook;
}
```

The unit test Jest code is the following:

```
describe('Given a function that is given as argument the id', () => {
  test('When invoked, it finds the book that matches such id', () => {

   const returnMokObject = {
      kind: 'books#volumes',
      totalItems: 1080,
      items: [
        {
          kind: 'books#volume',
          id: 'HN1dzQEACAAJ',
        }],
    };
   mockLocalstorageJest();
   const answer = catchSelectedBook('HN1dzQEACAAJ');
    expect(answer.id).toBe('HN1dzQEACAAJ');
  });
});
```

The function mockLocalstorageJest sends to the local storage an object so that it can be get when the function catchSelectedBook is tested
I export my function like this:

```
module.exports = {
  catchSelectedBook,mockLocalstorageJest,
};
```

And I import the function into the test file like this:

```
const { catchSelectedBook, mockLocalstorageJest} = require('./book-details.js');
```

Whenever I run the test, I got the following error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQsTT.png)

Does that mean that Jest doesn't have the array method "filter" defined?

Thanks!

Comment: It means that `localStorage.getItem('objecttransfer')` doesn't exist, so it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this instruction is returning null

```
const objectSearchAsString = localStorage.getItem('objecttransfer');
```

`JSON.parse(null)` returns null so `bookObject` is also null.

I believe that your problem is that you are not setting up the local storage correctly in `mockLocalstorageJest()`.

Comment: You are totally right. The function was sending to the local storage an object instead of an array, which is what the catchSelectedBook works with. Thanks!.

Comment: No worries @Pablo, and welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the most helpful answer to any
question you ask by clicking the check-mark (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)